Could not resolve require("./locale/**/*")
I am using Vite+React. I am getting error while running npm run dev.

"[ERROR] Could not resolve require("./locale/**/*")
node_modules/moment-with-locales-es6/node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:16645:
1 │ ...e&&module&&module.exports)try{b=Bf._abbr,require("./locale/"+a),$a(b)}catch(a){}return Ff[a]}function $a(a,b){v..."

I am using below versions of the packages.

React: 18.3.1
Vite: 5.4.1
moment: 2.30.1
moment-with-locales-es6: 2.18.1

I also added below code in vite.config.js file.
 resolve: {
    alias: {`your text`
        'moment$': 'moment/min/moment.with-locales.js',
    },
},

How to solve this problem?
I tried with multiple versions of Moment.js like 2.18.1, 2.25.2 etc.

I was able to solve this error after changing import syntax from
import moment from "moment"

to
import * as moment from "moment/moment"

